# JFrame - Loop over JButton ActionPerformed in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe, jbutton

I have a JFrame which contains a JPanel. The JPanel contains a JButton.

When the button is pressed, the application runs one Neo4j query and the content fills a TimeSeries JFreeChart. It works fine.

When I try to loop over it with a while, it just keeps running one query, instead of looping and running multiple queries.

```
public GraphExtensionLive(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String query = "NEO4J QUERY"
            //filling the chart...
}
     }
 }
```

I'd like to loop over this method but I can't do this simply putting a while loop. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain more and show more. You're not new to this site, so hopefully you know the requirements for questions here, including those of clarity, specificity and [mcve] code. Please help us understand your code and your problem so that we are able to post an answer.

Comment: For example, a loop over **what** operations? And you state that `"I can't do this simply putting a while loop."` -- why not? What happens when you do? As always, pertinent code will be key in helping us to better understand what's holding you back, and why your code is not working.

Comment: I did not add code but I think that now the question is better. What do you think?

Comment: Because your code likely does not respect Swing threading rules, and your while loop prevents the Swing event thread from working. But who knows for sure without your decent [mcve] post? Why are you not improving this question adequately?

Comment: About all I can say for now is "use a SwingWorker, including its process/publish methods" but I can't tell much more than that.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I tried to add a decent code.

Comment: Again use a SwingWorker or a Swing Timer, depending on how long the query takes.